# A error about \scalebox{h-scale}{text} code

Tags: scaling

I want to shrink the table below with \scalebox code, but I am getting an error. What could be the reason?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\cdot $ $(modI)$ & $0$ & $1$ & $x$ & $x+1$ & $x^{2}$ & $x^{2}+1$ & $x^{2}+x$
& $x^{2}+x+1$ \\ \hline
$0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $x$ & $x+1$ & $x^{2}$ & $x^{2}+1$ & $x^{2}+x$ & $x^{2}+x+1$
\\ \hline
$x$ & $0$ & $x$ & $x^{2}$ & $x^{2}+x$ & $x+1$ & $1$ & $x^{2}+x+1$ & $x^{2}+1$
\\ \hline
$x+1$ & $0$ & $x+1$ & $x^{2}+x$ & $x^{2}+1$ & $x^{2}+x+1$ & $x^{2}$ & $1$ & $%
x$ \\ \hline
$x^{2}$ & $0$ & $x^{2}$ & $x+1$ & $x^{2}+x+1$ & $x^{2}+x$ & $x$ & $x^{2}+1$
& $1$ \\ \hline
$x^{2}+1$ & $0$ & $x^{2}+1$ & $1$ & $x^{2}$ & $x$ & $x^{2}+x+1$ & $x+1$ & $%
x^{2}+x$ \\ \hline
$x^{2}+x$ & $0$ & $x^{2}+x$ & $x^{2}+x+1$ & $1$ & $x^{2}+1$ & $x+1$ & $x$ & $%
x^{2}$ \\ \hline
$x^{2}+x+1$ & $0$ & $x^{2}+x+1$ & $x^{2}+1$ & $x$ & $1$ & $x^{2}+x$ & $x^{2}$
& $x+1$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you shouldn't do that. You will get uneven fontsizes in your document. Use proper fontsize commands like \footnotesize to make the table smaller.

Comment: Delete `equation*` environment will do.

Comment: a `tabular` shouldn't be in `equation`, and neither `tabular` nor `equation` should be in `\scalebox` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: Thanks all the answers